# How would i check to see if the item in this database is available (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.6

[sql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcT1Z.jpg)

SQL database attached  as photo.

The maximum allowed quantity for item_id 12 is 7 at any given moment.
I want to write a program that will take a user's order and check the database to see if the desired quantity is available at the time that they want it.
the user will input a start date, end date and quantity.

I have tried many ways but my code seems to only check orders starting on the same exact dates as the user, instead of all orders of the same item that have overlapping time-frame.

This is the code I made so far:
Any help would be appreciated, need to add this feature to my end of year program.

```
    lines = ["EACKAH",12]
    conn = sqlite3.connect("accounts.sqlite3")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT start_date,end_date,duration,quantity FROM hirers WHERE item_id=?", (str(lines[1]),))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    print(data)
    cur.execute("SELECT quantity FROM on_sale WHERE item_id=?", (str(lines[1]),))
    max_qty = cur.fetchall()
    item_max = int(max_qty[0][0])
    cur.close()
    duration = [0.5,1,1.5,2.5,3]

    #load the desired quantity by the user
    qty_num = 0
    if (self.qty_entry.get()).isdigit() == True and int(self.qty_entry.get()) < 100:
        qty_num = int(self.qty_entry.get())
    else:
        qty_num = 0
    print("i..........", qty_num)

    #duration the user wants to hire the tool for
    self.index_duration = int(self.duration_list.curselection()[0])
    end_num = int(round(duration[self.index_duration],0))
    print("The user wants it for", end_num)


    check_count = 0
    if len(data) == 0:
        print("All Good")
    else:
        for i in data:
            lst = i
            print(lst)
            in_between = []
            counter  = 0
            dur = int(lst[2])
            sql_qty = lst[3]

            date_check = []
            while counter != dur:
                date_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(lst[0]), "%d-%m-%Y")
                end_date = date_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=counter)
                date_check.append(end_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
                counter = counter  + 1

            print(date_check)
            print("..........")
            for i in date_check:

                #load the current date
                d = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(self.date_entry.get()), "%d-%m-%Y")
                end = d + datetime.timedelta(days = end_num)
                #check for date overlaps
                if i == str(self.date_entry.get()) or i == end.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'):
                    #check quantity on overlap days
                    if int(item_max) - int(sql_qty) <= qty_num:
                        check_count = 0
                    else:
                        check_count = check_count + 1
                else:
                    check_count = 0

    if check_count == 0:
        self.old_date_check = True
    else:
        self.old_date_check = False

    print(self.old_date_check)
```

Comment: What duration from sqll query means? and what is duration = [0.5,1,1.5,2.5,3]?

Comment: @DejanDozet difference between start date and end date

Comment: @DejanDozet that's the allowed days you can have an item for

Comment: It is always difficult to read other people code and this one is hard for me to understand, so do you agree that I try to create a query so that you can execute to get the desired result?

Comment: @DejanDozet sure, I'll explain anything you need me to

Comment: So, some people are using (renting) some things (q-ty) for some period of time...

Comment: @DejanDozet yes exactly and I need code that checks to see if the amount they want is available

Comment: my idea is to break period (that new user wants) to exact dates and for every date keep q-ty for every order, and later just summarize everything per date and take maximum value for one date that is between dates new user wants it

Comment: @DejanDozet okay will try that way too. It will mean I have to create a second SQL table

Comment: I don't think second table is necessary, but query will have to take everything that is overlapping those days

Comment: @DejanDozet am going to rebuild the code with a second table now. Thanks for the help. Will let you know what happens

Comment: OK, and I will try to work it differently

Comment: @DejanDozet got it to work using your idea. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way I think:

First change date format to yyyy-mm-dd in the database

Put dates that user wants in an array (y_array) and loop through that array (remember to put every day in it - if user asked from 1.1.2018 to 3.1.2018 you have to put 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02 and 2018-01-03 etc.)

in that loop execute following sql:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) sum_quantity FROM hirers WHERE item_id= x and y between start_date and end_date
```

keep **maximum value** of sum_quantity in a variable in whole loop

after the loop you will have maximum quantity of items rented for one day between days user selected to rent